# VideoJS doesn´t play after pause RTMP live stream

Tags: html5-video, rtmp, video.js

I´m using VideoJS for a live stream from Wowza server but when I pause the player and them I play again the player does not recover the stream. I need to reload the webpage to start the stream again.

```
<video id="videoID" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" poster="/images/image.png"  controls="controls" width="320" height="240" data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash"]}'>
<source src="rtmp://www.myhost.com:1935/live/live.stream" type="rtmp/mp4" />
</video>
```

There are any method to do stop or VideoJS reload when the paused event appear?

EDIT: I've encountered the solution using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myPlayer = videojs('videoID');
videojs("videoID").ready(function(){
var myPlayer = this;
myPlayer.on("pause", function () {
myPlayer.on("play", function () { myPlayer.load (); myPlayer.off("play"); });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi I'm having the same issue as you and your solution seems to be the right direction but doesn't solve the issue entirely. After the second time I click play many other functions stop working. The large play button doesn't do go away and doesn't work either and the time doesn't get updated any more. Do you think there is a way to be more restrictive with the myPlayer.off("play")? I'm not exactly sure what's going on in that function either. It removes all of the event handlers that have been attached to the "play" element? or removes all of the actions that follow the event "play"?

Comment: "off" removes the specifed event. Not sure, why the play event is removed here.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so i found a solution. Instead of stripping all of the play events form the player you actually just need to edit the flash play event inside of video.dev.js on line 7337 (in version 4.11.4 i think). this is the line that says:

```
vjs.Flash.prototype.play = function(){
    this.el_.vjs_play();
};
```

it should be changed to say:

```
vjs.Flash.prototype.play = function(){
    this.el_.vjs_load();
    this.el_.vjs_play();
};
```

so that the load event is called before the play event.

Comment: This is good for the flash tool - anyone solve the problem for the html5 video element fallback?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = videojs('really-cool-video', { /* Options */}, function () {
        // ...

        var player = this;
        player.on("pause", function () {
            player.one("play", function () {
                player.load();
                player.play();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).