# Video.js doesn't resume after pause

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I try to use video.js for football translations, but when I press pause and press play again video is still paused.

[DEMO](http://dmytro.zarezenko.com/football/video.php)

What is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446868/videojs-doesn´t-play-after-pause-rtmp-live-stream

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1920).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = videojs('really-cool-video', { /* Options */}, function () {
        // ...

        var player = this;
        player.on("pause", function () {
            player.one("play", function () {
                player.load();
                player.play();
            });
        });
    });
});
```